# How to use Linq-to-SQL with Oracle database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, linq

I am trying to using Linq-to-SQL with an Oracle database. I had using `.dbml` file but its giving exception for Network Instance due to not available SQL Provider. So please guide me how can I use Linq-to-SQL with Oracle database.

Comment: I Tried the above link but did not work for me. There i am not able to setup connection.

Answer (score 3):

Linq-to-SQL is a **SQL Server** only solution - it was designed by the C# team (not the database folks) only as a "proof-of-concept" for the LINQ capabilities.

If you need support for other databases - like Oracle - you need to use **Entity Framework** instead (which was created and still is being further developed by the ADO.NET/database team at Microsoft)